# Select value / text / number from table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I am new to  Jquery / JS - as I'm playing with it for the first time this week.

I have a giant html table in a cfm file. It goes something like this:

...

```
<td nowrap align="center"><INPUT readonly type="text" name="ttct"  SIZE="5"></td>
<td nowrap align="center"><INPUT readonly type="text" name="ttemp"  SIZE="5"></td>
<td nowrap align="center"><INPUT readonly type="text" name="ttpdp"  SIZE="5"></td>
```

...

The values of these cells are set elsewhere in the JS. What I want to do is select all of the cells that have a particular value (zero, in this case), and set them to null.

In a separate js file, I have a function which says:

...

```
$('input[name^="t"]').filter('input[name$="p"]').val('')
$('input[name^="t"]').filter('input[name$="d"]').val('')
$('input[name^="r"]').filter('input[name$="p"]').val('')
$('input[name^="r"]').filter('input[name$="d"]').val('')
```

...

Which selects ALL of the cells. How do I filter that to only set those which are zero to null, instead of ALL of the cells?

I've been trying a lot of things to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('td input:text').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == 0; }).val("");
```

or

```
$('td input:text[value="0"]').val("");
```

Comment: perfect. That makes way more sense than what I was trying. Thanks for the quick and accurate reply.

Comment: that second one was more along the lines of what I was trying, but I was trying to expand on my $('input[name^="r"]').filter('input[name$="d"]').val('') line already...something like $('input[name^="r"]').filter('input[name$="d"]').text().val('')

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for the edit, didn't realise [value="0"] would work for typed values.